# asp.net works fine in debug mode and gives oracle error when published to iis 7

Tags: asp.net, oracle, iis-7, ado.net

I have an asp.net 3.5 website that connects to oracle database. when I work inside visual studio 2008 and test website for a heavy resource consuming page it works fine. but when I publish this site to IIS 7 (on windows server 2008, or windows 7) it causes oracle listener to fall down. any ideas on what might cause this problem is welcomed.

> ErrorMessage: ORA-12516: TNS:listener could not find available handler
>   with matching protocol. Stack
>
> StackTrace: at
>   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException.Check(OciErrorHandle
>   errorHandle, Int32 rc) at
>   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection.OpenOnLocalTransaction(String
>   userName, String password, String serverName, Boolean
>   integratedSecurity, Boolean unicode, Boolean omitOracleConnectionName)
>   at
>   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection..ctor(OracleConnectionString
>   connectionOptions) at
>   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool,
>   DbConnection owningObject) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) at
>   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.Open() at
>   DMS.Data.Database.DatabaseConnection.getCommand(String sqlString,
>   Boolean isTransaction) in E:\DMS
>   WORK\CRM9\db\DatabaseConnection.cs:line 561 at
>   DMS.Data.Database.DatabaseConnection.CreateDatasetWithoutTransaction(String
>   sqlString) in E:\DMS WORK\CRM9\db\DatabaseConnection.cs:line 878 at
>   DMS.CRM.Today.FillRep() in e:\DMS WORK\CRM9\DMSCRM\today.aspx.cs:line
>   160 at DMS.CRM.Today.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in e:\DMS
>   WORK\CRM9\DMSCRM\today.aspx.cs:line 65 at
>   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object
>   o, Object t, EventArgs e) at
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Comment: can you show how you open and close the connections to the database from your C# code? the error could be related to configuration issues or there could be too many connections open. Are all the Oracle drivers properly available/installed on the web server?

Answer (score 1):

Is this 32-bit or 64-bit windows? If it is 64-bit then you need to install oracle 64-bit drivers along with the 32-bit drivers. or change your application build to x86 only.

Comment: @Nahbeet - that will not throw this error.  If you have bit level issues you get a bad format / image exception thrown.

Comment: No, if your application code is 64-bit then it requires 64-bit oracle drivers. Your application cannot use 32-bit oracle drivers because it can't find them. I don't remember the exact error so it may not be the same as your error but you should definitely look into what kind of drivers you have installed and whether they are compatible with your aplplication code.

Comment: That is correct.  You must use like bitness.  If you mismatch them you get issues such as Bad Format Exceptions, Invalid Image libraries, etc.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this could also happen if you "build configuration" says "Any CPU".